# Flickering started: All 4 LED bulbs on dimmer switch flicker in unison

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, led, dimmer-switch

All 4 LED Recessed lights on dimmer switch #1 just started flickering in sync (sometimes) starting 2 days ago.

- 4 years with no problem
- 4 other LED's on a DIFFERENT dimmer switch #2 (but same circuit) also flicker sometimes, whether the dimmer switch #1 is on or not.
- It doesn't matter how bright I have the dimmer

We've had bad weather for the past few days. Maybe the solar panels are not giving off enough power during rain/clouds?

Or maybe Edison is having to send power since solar is not netting enough power - and Edison delivery is not strong because of the bad weather/rain?

Is it dangerous if the lights are on? If they are off?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are we talking about a stand-alone/off-grid solar system, or a grid-tied solar system?

Comment: Is the dimmer rated for LEDs?  Are the LEDs rated for dimming?

Comment: It is a grid-tied solar system.

Comment: LEDs are dimmable. I could turn Dimmer #1 on and it would flicker, then turn it back off and then on again and it would not flicker. Then it would flicker if I turned it back on a 3rd time. The same with Dimmer #2 - sometimes those LEDs would dim when turned on.

Since that day (and maybe the next?) it's been fine.

I also worried that since it was raining - maybe water leaked onto an exposed wire? But it's rained a lot since then and they have been fine.

Also... Edison turned power off 3 days after the problem for 15 minutes at midnight to "repair" something in our neighborhood.

Comment: Well, if you can't get out to check for a rain soaked wire, then best bet is not use them, or worry until you can. Also, the LED bulbs could be at their end of life, or your dimmer(s) are malfunctioning. Can you pull the dimmers and disconnect them and use a standard toggle switch to see if the dimmer is the issue? Perhaps change the bulbs? A few ideas to help during the rainy times.